# Unable to change the configuration of my new Regolith Linux installation

Tags: ubuntu, i3, tiling-wm, regolith

I am a new user of Regolith Linux. I'm just using the Desktop version with a Ubuntu 18.04. I followed the instructions on the website to customize my desktop by creating a new configuration file from the original:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/regolith/i3
$ cp /etc/regolith/i3/config ~/.config/regolith/i3/config
```

After modifying the configuration file (to test, I just changed the name of a workspace), and reloading i3, the changes don't seem to be applied.

Can someone help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to log out and back in (just once) after creating my user directory i3 config file before i3 will pick it up.

PS: You can verify which i3 config file you're using with `i3 --moreversion`.

Answer (score 0):

The path for the i3-config is usually "~/.i3/config" or "~/.config/i3/config".  Try copying to one of these instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I tried to do this, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

An easy to reload your setup on the fly is: Super + Shift + r

Otherwise you can always log out (as previously mentioned) with: Super + Shift + e

I suspect you didn't change the i3 config file correctly make sure you remove the system default and implement your own settings.

Answer (score -2):

My config is at: `/etc/regolith/i3/config`

Comment: Notice that the OP specifically copied that file locally in an attempt to customize it.